# When Using Youtube Embed Code with start end and rel=0 attributes video goes back to zero when it ends not start offset

Tags: video, youtube

Here is my embed code with responsive wrapper:

```
<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;"><iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G64faDylbgc?feature=oembed&start=605&end=11704&rel=0" frameborder="5px" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
```

The video starts at the correct time and ends at the correct time however when it reaches the end it goes back to the beginning at time=0 instead of going back to time=start.  I do not have access to javascript nor will I ever.
Is this behavior by design or is it a bug? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this behaviour is by design.

And to my knowledge, you cannot override the replay button, so the easiest thing is probably to add a line of text saying when it starts.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I assume you mean replay button? I'm not using a replay button and I can not use a loop either.  Perhaps I wasn't very clear let me explain further.  Without the rel=0 when my video ends it would load the player with some other related video kinda like "Up Next" video.  But by specifying rel=0 it will not show anther video up next, instead it returns to the beginning of the same video that just ended without clicking on any button.   I believe it return to the specified "start" position and wait for you to click the play button again.

Comment: Yes, I meant replay, sorry about that. I tried your code and on my computer the video ends and a replay button appears. When clicked, the video starts from time=0

Comment: I believe the Replay button is a plugin that you must have installed in your browser, I have not installed such a plugin an wouldn't want to force a viewer to install a replay button plugin on their computer. You say it restarts at time=0 as well at least it is consistently wrong. It doesn't seem logical that this behavior would be by design does it?

Comment: That you for all your device I decided to fix the problem on the front-end by using the Enhancements Trim function in the YouTube editor